# Scoped std::unique_ptr cast

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

I'm currently working on some code using smart pointers in which it is necessary at a number of points to cast these pointers to their base types and pass them as const arguments to functions. Currently I'm using shared_ptr's and the standard pointer casting functions to achieve this, but this seems inefficient (as each cast costs at least one CAS) and also misleading (as we are not modelling a shared relationship, the parent is the sole owner of the object).

I therefore came up with the following but wanted to check it is indeed safe, or is there some edge case which will break it?

```
template <typename ToType, typename FromType>
class FTScopedCastWrapper {
public:
    explicit FTScopedCastWrapper(std::unique_ptr<FromType>& p) : from_ptr_(&p) {
        auto d = static_cast<ToType *>(p.release());
        to_ptr_ = std::unique_ptr<ToType>(d);
    }

    ~FTScopedCastWrapper() {
        auto d = static_cast<FromType *>(to_ptr_.release());
        (*from_ptr_) = std::unique_ptr<FromType>(d);
    }

    const std::unique_ptr<ToType>& operator()() {
        return to_ptr_;
    }


    // Prevent allocation on the heap
    void* operator new(size_t) = delete;
    void* operator new(size_t, void*) = delete;
    void* operator new[](size_t) = delete;
    void* operator new[](size_t, void*) = delete;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<FromType>* from_ptr_;
    std::unique_ptr<ToType> to_ptr_;
};

template <typename ToType, typename FromType>
FTScopedCastWrapper<ToType, FromType> FTScopedCast(std::unique_ptr<FromType>& p) {
    return FTScopedCastWrapper<ToType, FromType>(p);
}
```

The intended usage is then

```
void testMethod(const std::unique_ptr<Base>& ptr) {
    // Do Stuff
}

auto ptr = std::make_unique<Derived>();
testMethod(FTScopedCast<Base>(ptr)());
```

The deleter is not carried across as doing so would prevent upcasting. It also doesn't make sense to do so as the deleter will never be invoked on the created smart pointer anyway.

Allocation on the heap is prevented as it could allow the wrapper to outlive the pointer it wraps, copying is prevented by the std::unique_ptr member and standard destruction order will ensure the raw pointer is returned to the original smart pointer before it is destroyed, even if it is declared in the same scope as the wrapper.

I'm aware this is not thread safe but I'd argue sharing a unique_ptr between threads is breaking its contract of a single owner.

Comment: Consider flipping the logic around and have the objects call the functions. They know their type, so no more casts.

Comment: If `testMethod` isn't intended to affect ownership, then why bother having it take a reference to a unique_ptr at all? It seems like making it take a `Base*` or `Base&` would simplify this situation and remove the need to juggle any kind of smart pointer.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish You're right and in fact the interface used to look like that, I just decided that it was time for me to embrace C++11 and might have gotten a little over zealous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the intention is to "steal" the contents of a `std::unique_ptr` for the duration of the function call, and then return it to its original owner when the function call is complete.

But this just seems needlessly convoluted. For a start, as pointed out by @TheUndeadFish in the comments, you could just take a raw `Base*` as the function argument and call it with `std::unique_ptr::get()`. As long as the called function doesn't do something silly like call `delete` on the passed-in pointer or squirrel it away in a static variable for later use then this will work just fine.

Alternatively, if you find raw pointers completely distasteful, you could use a non-owning pointer wrapper, something like the following (untested, but you get the idea):

```
template <typename T>
class unowned_ptr {
public:
    unowned_ptr() = default;
    unowned_ptr(const unowned_ptr&) = default;
    unowned_ptr& operator=(const unowned_ptr&) = default;

    template <typename U>
    unowned_ptr(const U* other) : ptr(other) {}

    template <typename U>
    unowned_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<U>& other) : ptr(other.get()) {}

    T* operator->() { return ptr; }
    const T* operator->() const { return ptr; }

private:
    T* ptr = nullptr;
};
```

Something very similar to this, `std::observer_ptr` ("the world's dumbest smart pointer") was proposed for C++17, but I'm not sure of the status.

Comment: [N4282 "The World's Dumbest Smart Pointer"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4282.pdf) was [incorporated into the Library Fundamentals TS v2](https://github.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/commit/b5441486c6944c2fcc40a820660f451380ba253b) at the [Urbana meeting in November](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html#LWG24).

Comment: I quite like the idea of the unowned_ptr but I think following your suggestion I'll just use raw pointers and trust people not to do stupid things. Thanks.

Comment: "“I use raw pointers
for non-owning relationships. And I actually *like* them. And I don’t find them difficult or error
prone.” - Howard Hinnant. It's good to see the occasional answer that breaks away from the smart-pointer cargo cult.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus I'm not sure that what Howard Hinnant considers easy is true for the rest of us! Personally, I can understand the motivation behind `observer_ptr`, in that it allows us to say, for new projects, "never use raw pointers", in the same way that `make_unique()` lets us say "never use `new`". Whether it will turn out to be popular remains to be seen.